# Splitting fields of subalgebras of central division algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions, division-algebras

Suppose $D$ is a central division algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$. Let $A \subset D$ be a subalgebra, say also central over $\mathbb{Q}$ (to restrict the degree of generality). Now if a field $L$ (e.g. $L= \mathbb{R}$) splits $D$, then what can we say about about the splitting behaviour of $A$ with respect to $L$?

If $L$ can both split $A$ or not, do we have easy concrete examples? To avoid trivial situations, suppose that $\deg A \geq 2$ and that $A \neq D$.

Comment: You will have to be more precise about what "$A$ splits" means., because $A$ is not necessarily simple...

Comment: @GreginGre Am I missing something? Isn't $A$ automatically a division algebras, hence simple? It is a f.d. $\Bbb{Q}$-algebra without zero divisors, so every non-zero element $a$ has both a left inverse and a right inverse by the usual argument (left/right multiplication by $a$ is injective, hence surjective). The one-sided inverses then coincide by associativity etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Would this question be more appropriate for mathoverflow?

Comment: No need to post to MO. I have a full answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is supposed to be central, the answer is YES.

Since $A$ is central and simple (thanks, Jyrki), the Centralizer theorem shows that $D\simeq A\otimes_k B$, where $B=C_D(A)$

I claim that $A,B$ have coprime degrees.
Since we work over $\mathbb{Q}$, and since $D,A,B$ are division, $\deg(A)\deg(B)=\deg(D)=\mathrm{ind}(D)=\exp(D)=\mathrm{lcm}(\exp(A),\exp(B))=\mathrm{lcm}(\deg(A), \deg(B))$.
Hence $\gcd(\deg(A),\deg(B))=1.$

Now if $D_L$ is split (where $D_L=D\otimes_k L)$, then $A_L\sim B^{op}_L$ (where $\sim$ is the Brauer equivalence), so $\mathrm{ind}(A_L)=\mathrm{ind}(B^{op}_L)=\mathrm{ind}(B_L)$

Now  $\mathrm{ind}(A_L)\mid\deg(A_L)=\deg(A)$, and similarly $\mathrm{ind}(B_L)\mid \deg(B)$. Hence $\mathrm{ind}(A_L)=\mathrm{ind}(B_L) $ divides  $\gcd(\deg(A),\deg(B))=1.$ Hence $A_L$ is split and $B_L$ is split.

Comment: If $D_L$ is split, then wouldn't the Brauer class of $A_L$ be equal to the inverse class of $B_L$? I picture this as $1=[D_L] = [A_L \otimes B_L] = [A_L] \cdot [B_L]$ in terms of classes. Anyway, even if it were like this, the exponents would still be equal.

Comment: And the index of the opossite algebra $A_L^*$ giving the inverse of $A$ in the Brauer group is equal to the index of $A$. I think I got it, thanks!

Comment: Nice! Some surprises for me in here. I would have thought that an index four division algebra over center $\Bbb{Q}$ may well have an index two central sub algebra, but apparently that is not the case. I missed the use of centralizer theorem totally, and was on a totally wrong track trying to work with Hasse invariants.

Comment: @Radu T, you're right , this is a misprint